# fdm - nested actions

Tags: email

I am trying to sort incoming mails from a ticket system into maildirs containing the ticket number.

The sender is: `ticketsys@test.de`

The Subject contains always: `RequestID: <numbers>`

So I tried with the following ruleset:

```
match "^From:.*ticketsys@test\.de"             in headers {
   match "^Subject:.*RequestID:[  \t]*([0-9]*)" action tag "ticketno" value "%1" continue
    match matched action "ticket"
    match unmatched action keep
}
```

The action ticket looks like this:

```
action "ticket"        maildir  "%h/Mails/work/INBOX.Ticket-%[ticketno]"
```

It matches but the newly created folder ends with the minus sign ( `Mails/work/INBOX.Ticket-` ) as if the tag was not successful.

**Update:**

Here are logs from `fdm -kvvvv fetch`:

```
WORK: trying (match) message 26
WORK: matching from 0 to 1586 (size=3876, body=1586)
WORK: tried regexp "^From:.*ticketsys@test\.de" in headers, result now 1
WORK: finished rule 17, result 1
WORK: matched to rule 17
WORK: entering nested rules
WORK: trying (match) message 26
WORK: matching from 0 to 3876 (size=3876, body=1586)
WORK: tried regexp "^Subject:.*RequestID:[      ]*([0-9]*)" in any, result now 1
WORK: finished rule 18, result 1
WORK: matched to rule 18
WORK: action <rule 18>:0 (tag), user andres
WORK: match message 26, deliver
WORK: trying (deliver) message 26
WORK: message 26, running action <rule 18>:0 (tag) as user andres
WORK: tagging message: ticketno ()
WORK: message 26 delivered (rule 18, tag) in 0.000 seconds
WORK: trying (deliver) message 26
WORK: deliver message 26, blocked
WORK: calling fetch state (0x416b00, flags 0x00)
WORK: 5 file descriptors in use
WORK: deliver started, pid 10023
WORK: deliver user is: andres (1001/1001), home is: /home/andres
WORK: saving to maildir /home/andres/Mails/work/INBOX.Ticket-
WORK: creating /home/andres/Mails/work
WORK: trying /home/andres/Mails/work/INBOX.Ticket-/tmp/1485412884.10023_0.HGL-049
WORK: writing to /home/andres/Mails/work/INBOX.Ticket-/tmp/1485412884.10023_0.HGL-049
WORK: moving .../tmp/1485412884.10023_0.HGL-049 to .../new/1485412884.10023_0.HGL-049
WORK: reading mail from: /home/andres/Mails/work/INBOX/cur/1485348562_1.29104.HGL-049,U=443306,FMD5=7e33429f656f1e6e9d79b29c3f82c57e:2,S
```

The ticketno was not writtern to the maildir.

**Update 2:**

Updated to latest fdm version to ensure all fixes are included

How can I write the tag into the maildir name?

**Update 3:**

The Subject line looks like this:

```
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Empfangsbest=E4tigung_f=FCr_Service?=
        =?iso-8859-1?Q?_Request_mit_der_Service_RequestID:?=
        =?iso-8859-1?Q?_1710000261_/__Domain:.test.de?=
        =?iso-8859-1?Q?_Subdmonains_f=FCr_Staging_Zwecke?=
```

Comment: It seems to work ok for me (fdm version 1.8 on fedora 23). Try running with `-vvv` to see if you can see where it is going wrong.

Comment: @meuh Updated my question

Comment: You should be seeing `tagging message: ticketno (123)` where for example 123 is the matched number. So there must be a problem with your regexp: for some reason `[0-9]*` is matching 0 characters. Look for some non-printing characters in your subject line. Perhaps it is encoded? Look at the line with `grep Subject: <mailfile|cat -vt`.

Comment: @meuh Does not look like there are. Except it spans multiple lines in the mailfile -> added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `fdm` does not do MIME-Header decoding, so when a mail header has been encoded, eg as `=?iso-8859-1?Q?...`, you will have to explicitly take this into account in your regexp. Note that fdm will join multi-line headers into one line during the regexp phase to help you.

So, if you can guarantee that the sender of the mail will always use exactly the same header encoding you could replace your regexp with something like

```
match "^Subject:.*RequestID:.*\?Q\?_([0-9]*)" action tag "ticketno" value "%1" continue
```

so that you skip over the encoding header. However, a cleaner solution would be to introduce some perl code (or similar) to decode the header into uft8 and then match with your original regexp. Create a file, say `/tmp/decodesubject`, with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use open qw/:std :encoding(utf-8)/;
use Mail::Header; # perl-MailTools
use Encode;
my $head = new Mail::Header \*STDIN, FoldLength=>999;
my $subject = $head->get('Subject');
$subject = Encode::decode('MIME-Header', $subject); # -> utf8
print "Subject: $subject";
```

and make it executable with `chmod +x /tmp/decodesubject`. You may need to install a package such as `perl-MIME-tools` or `libmime-tools-perl` to get the `Mail::Header` functions.
The script reads a mail on stdin and prints just the decoded Subject header. To call it from your config file, replace the above `match` line with

```
match pipe "/tmp/decodesubject" returns (0,"Subject:.*RequestID:[ \t]*([0-9]*)")
action tag "ticketno" value "%[command1]" continue
```

Note that to get at the capture groups in the regexp of a `pipe` command it seems you cannot use `%1` but must use `"%[command1]"`.